# Sort list by index

Tags: c#

I get a string: z|a|b|c|a|b|c|a|b|c

I would like three arrays or lists: arrayOne = a a a, arrayTwo = b b b, arrayThree = c c c

so far I split the string like this

```
List<string> myList = myString.Split('|').ToList();
```

z,a,b,c can be any string value

any help would be appreciated.

```
arrayOne = myListIndex 1,4,7
arrayTwo= myListIndex 2,5,8
arrayThree = myListIndex 3,6,9
```

but myList can be any length

Comment: What is the condition to break it into 3 lists?

Comment: What is the reason (condition) you don't want "z" in any list? Is it because it is the first item in the list? And are "a", "b" and "c" always following each other in this particular order

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need to use [`GroupBy()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the lists:

```
var result = myString.Split('|').ToList()
    .GroupBy(c => c)
    .Select(g => g.ToList())
```

Here are the results in LinqPad:

[image: Results]

Answer (score 2):

Skip the first item and use `Index mod 3` to get the desired lists.

```
string myString = "z|a|b|c|a|b|c|a|b|c";
List<List<string>> result = myString.Split('|').Skip(1)
        .Select((s, i) => new { s, i })
        .GroupBy(x => x.i % 3)
        .Select(g => g.Select(c => c.s).ToList())
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.GroupBy()`

```
myList.GroupBy(a => a).Select(group => group.ToList());
```

This will be you a collection of lists that you want.

If you keep the groups you can see what `Key` the collections are grouped by.

Comment: See the title and the edited question. OP wants to get items according to their indexes not by values(`GroupBy(a => a)`)

Answer (score 0):

Skip the first item and divide the rest into three lists, taking every 3rd element

```
    var arrayOne = myList.Skip(1).Where((x, i) => i % 3 == 0).ToList();
    var arrayTwo = myList.Skip(1).Where((x, i) => i % 3 == 1).ToList();
    var arrayThree = myList.Skip(1).Where((x, i) => i % 3 == 2).ToList();
```